# Find Matrix A from Linear Transformation T

Tags: linear-algebra, linear-transformations

[image: Graphic Visual]

Given the following two graphics I need to matrix A so that T(x) = Ax.

What I see is that **0** is a fixed point at the origin after the transformation, so I don't need to worry about it when finding matrix **A**.

I also found that:

b* = 2[0 1/2]<sup>T</sup>

a* = 2[1/2 0]<sup>T</sup>

c* = 3[1/3 1/3]<sup>T</sup>

Now I don't know how I can use this to find the matrix A. What is especially confusing to me is that **a** and **b** have swapped places so I don't know how it will effect the matrix **A**.

Sorry for the formatting.

Comment: Try finding the matrix of $T^{-1}$, which looks a lot easier to me, and then invert it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Look at $T^{-1}$. As the columns of $A^{-1}$ you can choose the vectors 1. going from $0$ to $a$ and 2. going from $0$ to $b$. The vector from $0$ to $a$ is $(1,2)^T$ and the other one is $(2,1)^T$, so we get

$$A^{-1}=\begin{pmatrix} 1 & 2 \\ 2 & 1 \end{pmatrix}.$$

Inverting yields

$$A=\frac{1}{3}\begin{pmatrix} -1 & 2 \\ 2 & -1 \end{pmatrix}.$$

Our transformation map is then

$$T: \mathbb{R}^2 \longrightarrow \mathbb{R}^2, \ x \longmapsto Ax = \frac{1}{3}\begin{pmatrix} -1 & 2 \\ 2 & -1 \end{pmatrix}x.$$

Comment: What do you mean by looking at T^-1? The matrix A if the transformation was instead going from a square to a parallelogram?

Comment: @PeraltaLearns Yes. That matrix is very easy to construct if you remember that the columns of a transformation matrix are the images of the basis vectors.

Comment: @Jan Gotcha thanks!

Comment: @PeraltaLearns I mixed up the notation. See my edited answer now.

Answer (score 1):

We have $$T(3,3)= (1,1)\;\;\;{\rm and}\;\;\;T(2,1)= (0,1)$$ so $$T(1,0) = (-{1\over 3},{2\over 3})  \;\;\;{\rm and}\;\;\;   T(1,0) = ({2\over 3},-{1\over 3})$$

and thus $$T= \begin{pmatrix}-{1\over 3}&{2\over 3}\\ {2\over 3}&-{1\over 3} \end{pmatrix} $$

---

Edit $$T(3,0) =3T(2,1)-T(3,3) = (0,3)-(1,1) = (-1,2)$$ now we divide this by 3 and thus  $$T(1,0) = (-{1\over 3},{2\over 3}) $$ Similary for $T(0,1)$

Comment: Can you please explain that second line? Where did you get the point (1,0) since its not included in the parallelogram. Also how can the T(1,0) equal to two different coordinates? Thanks.